# How to match C struct conditional field with golang struct field

Tags: c, go, struct

I ran into issue with https://github.com/cilium/cilium/pull/17370#discussion_r731170618, where in order to save memory space, the suggestion is to make a conditional field like below:

```
 struct remote_endpoint_info {
        __u32           sec_label;
        __u32           tunnel_endpoint;
#ifdef ENABLE_VTEP
        mac_t           vtep_mac;
#endif
        __u8            key;
 };
```

but it cause misalignment issue with golang struct below:

```
// RemoteEndpointInfo implements the bpf.MapValue interface. It contains the
// security identity of a remote endpoint.
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen=true
   +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=github.com/cilium/cilium/pkg/bpf.MapValue
type RemoteEndpointInfo struct {
        SecurityIdentity uint32        `align:"sec_label"`
        TunnelEndpoint   types.IPv4    `align:"tunnel_endpoint"`
        VtepMAC          mac.Uint64MAC `align:"vtep_mac"`
        Key              uint8         `align:"key"`
}
```

I wonder if I could do

```
 struct remote_endpoint_info {
        __u32           sec_label;
        __u32           tunnel_endpoint;
        mac_t           vtep_mac __maybe_unused;
        __u8            key;
 };
```

I got no misalignment error report, but does it really save memory space like  the conditional `ifdef ENABLE_VTEP`

Comment: The `#ifdef` in the C code means that you either generate program A, where there are three fields in the struct, or binary-incompatible-program B, where there are four. Go doesn't really have an equivalent thing. Instead, in Go we're encouraged not to expose internal details (like exact layouts and alignments of internal structures) by encoding and decoding data into portable formats.

Comment: is there proper solution for this ? I saw __maybe_unused used for stack variable, wonder if __maybe_unused could work for struct field, the llvm compiler did not complain error, but it has no effect on that after I use pahole to show the binary struct output

Comment: The `__maybe_unused` annotation is a peculiarly-spelled way to say "hey mister compiler, please don't complain if this is unused, it's here because it has to be here for reasons *you* can't see". The double underscores put this in a restricted namespace that *users* are not allowed to use; this allows *implementors* to silence warnings from their library implementations, by expanding `__abc` to `__pragma("suppress warning 4412")` or whatever. Each specific compiler that has the warning has a *different number* but the `__foo` keyword expands to the right one for *that compiler*.

Comment: This particular weirdness was invented back in the late 1990s when we had explosions of various C compilers (gcc, pcc, lcc, icc, turbo-C, etc), each of which had rather different ways of doing things. [Modern C++ has actual language syntax for annotations](https://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/18/cxx11-generalized-attributes/), obviating the need for `__maybe_unused`, but backwards compatibility and general inertia keep them used.

Comment: Go, being a modern language, discourages this kind of "work around ugly backwards compatibility issue with klunky pervasive trick that makes compilation slow, programs hard to understand or port, and generally makes life miserable for everyone" trick. So there's just nothing *like this* **in** Go. The closest thing Go has to this is the `build` directive. (Whether you can use that for this case, and if so how, I don't know.)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I guess I will have to live with the fact to have the C struct with the field to be non-conditional, I don't really know how much  impact to have that field when it is not used, maybe just extra memory, so? seems not worth the effort to save memory space or maybe there is performance impact? I don't know :)

Comment: There's definitely a memory-usage-impact if there are many instances of the data structure. When building C programs on tiny embedded systems with (say) only 32k or 1MB of data space that's currently 95% used, this might be important. That's ... less common, shall we say, in systems that run Go programs :-)

Comment: thanks again, i might find alternative solution without adding the field in C struct at all, but that may be specific to Cilium project since it seems providing alternative after I looked into further :)